# BibTeX, citing a podcast

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, chicago-style

What's the best way to cite a podcast using BibTeX, to match the Chicago Manual of Style?

My guesses are: `online`, `misc`, `audio`, `music`.

It's a recorded lecture, if that matters.

Comment: Which BibTeX style do you use?

Comment: I'm using the biblatex-chicago style. The Manual gives a podcast example here: http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch14/ch14_sec221.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Originally posted as a comment by Ben VB.)

```
@music{olsen,
  author={Corey Olsen},
  title={Ainulind\"ale},
  booktitle={Silmarillion Seminar},
  month=dec,
  year=2010,
  date={December 8, 2010},
  series={Podcast audio},
  url={http://www.tolkienprofessor.com/audio/silmarillion_1.mp3}
}
```

gets me almost there, although the letter "p" in "podcast audio" should be lowercase in note and uppercase in bibliography; this does uppercase in both.

Comment: I guess I'll take it, as it's the closest to correct I've been able to get.

Comment: Is there a way to specify a specific time range within a podcast in the citation, or a preferred way of stating that in the text? (Ex: from 5:20-5:55). I'd like to cite the same podcast at different points in time.

Comment: why not @misc @audio?

Comment: If the capitalisation of "podcast audio" is an issue, `series={\autocap{p}odcast audio},` may help, but that will depend on the exact style and other factors (probably beyond the scope of this general question).

Answer (score 2):

```
@music{Day2014,
  author={Zella Day},
  title={East of Eden},
  booktitle={East of Eden},
  publisher={B3SCI Records},
  month=7,
  year=2014,
  url={http://music.163.com/#/song/29009655?userid=3615376}
}

@audio{Smith2018,
  author={Stacey Vanek Smith and Stanley Plotkin},
  title={The Economics of Vaccines},
  howpublished={NPR},
  organization={Planet Money}
  month=6,
  year=2010,
  series={Planet Money},
  url={https://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=616926505}
}
```

**Reference**

Lehman, Philipp, Philip Kime, Moritz Wemheuer, Audrey Boruvka, and Joseph Wright. 2018. The Biblatex Package: Programmable Bibliographies and Citations. http://mirrors.cqu.edu.cn/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf.

Comment: for anyone c+p-ing the @audio example above there is a missing comma at the end of organization