# How do I cite a podcast in BibLaTeX using the author-year style?

Tags: biblatex, koma-script, authoryear

I've already read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579757/citing-a-podcast-in-apa-style-with-biblatex-and-biber) post concering this topic, but their solution does not work with the `authoryear` style that I am required to use for my paper.

My code looks a little something like this:

```latex
\documentclass[
    paper=A4,
    pagesize=auto
    12pt,
    ngerman,
    usegeometry,
    oneside,
    headinclude=false,
    footinclude=true,
    BCOR=0mm,
    DIV=calc,
    parskip=onehalf,
    bibliography=totocnumbered,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[toc=bibliographynumbered, style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}

\addbibressource{literatur.bib}

\begin{document}
Wie in Kapitel 2 hinlänglich beschrieben handelt es sich bei Queerness nicht um eine 
Szeneangehörigkeit, sondern primär um das Abweichen der sexuellen Orientierung und/oder 
Geschlechtsidentität eines Menschen von der gesellschaftlichen Norm. In manchen Kontexten 
lässt sich zwar durchaus von einer queeren Szene sprechen, diese ist jedoch höchst heterogen,
oftmals lokal fragmentiert, und es gehören nicht alle queeren Menschen auch zwangsläufig 
dieser Szene an \parencite[vgl.][]{WiC80}. 
\end{document
```

and this would be the according entry in my `bibliography`-file:

```latex
@audio{WiC80,
    author = {given=Kathi, family=Roeb and given=Julian, family=Wenzel},
    author+an:role = {=hosts},
    date = {2022-10-26},
    entrysubtype = {Podcast-Folge},
    mainsubtitle = {Der queere Podcast von PULS},
    maintitle = {Willkommen im Club},
    number = {80},
    subtitle = {},
    title = {\glqq Ich fühle mich nicht als Teil der queeren Community!\grqq},
    url = {https://www.ardaudiothek.de/episode/willkommen-im-club-der-queere-podcast-von-puls/ich-fuehle-mich-nicht-als-teil-der-queeren-community-80/puls/12041705/},
    urldate = {2023-03-16},
    year = {2022},
}
```

Nevertheless, the output after compiling does look nothing like what it should look like:
[image: Bibliography after compiling]

whereas I'd want it to be:

> Roeb, Kathi/Wenzel, Julian (26. Okt. 2022) (Hosts). "Ich fühle mich nicht als Teil der queeren Community!" In: Willkommen im Club. Der queere Podcast von PULS. 80. Podcast. Verfügbar unter: ardaudiothek.de/episode/…. [zuletzt geprüft: 16.03.2023].

Comment: The linked answer is for `biblatex-apa`. APA style has very specific guidelines as to what podcast references should look like. The generic `biblatex` standard styles of the `authoryear` family usually aim for a more simple/uniform output. So it is not surprising that even with the data as shown in the linked answer (entered in a way suitable for `biblatex-apa`), you don't quite get the same result.

Comment: What output would you like to see? The screenshot you show is not what the (slightly defective) MWE would produce, but it is close enough that I can't see why you are unhappy with what you get only for podcasts and not generally (some of the differences can be addressed by FAQs such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864). I assume you have something else in mind. Can you explain what you want in more detail, please?

Comment: @moewe I'd like to have something like:
Roeb, Kathi/Wenzel, Julian (26. Okt. 2022) (Hosts). "Ich fühle mich nicht als Teil der queeren Community!" In: Willkommen im Club. Der queere Podcast von PULS. 80. Podcast. Verfügbar unter: https://www.ardaudiothek.de/episode/willkommen-im-club-der-queere-podcast-von-puls/ich-fuehle-mich-nicht-als-teil-der-queeren-community-80/puls/12041705/. [zuletzt geprüft: 16.03.2023}.

Comment: I see. Please edit that into the question to make it more explicit.

Comment: I probably won't have time to look into this in more detail, but the `@audio` entry type does not really allow for the "in:". You might be able to get closer to what you want if you abuse the `@incollection` or `@inbook` entry type. (The episode title would go into the `title` field, the podcast title into `booktitle`. The standard styles don't print the `role` name annotations - this is an APA thing - , you could look into the `authortype` field).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create your own entry type `audio` and customize it as you wish, see [How can I create entirely new data types with BibLaTeX/Biber?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175776/how-can-i-create-entirely-new-data-types-with-biblatex-biber).

In my example, the management of "role" is a bit "artisanal". There is the field `role` in case the role is the same for both authors. If any author has a different role I used `prefix`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@audio{WiC80,
    author = {given=Kathi, family=Roeb and given=Julian, family=Wenzel},
    role = {hosts},
    date = {2022-10-26},
    entrysubtype = {Podcast},
    mainsubtitle = {Der queere Podcast von PULS},
    maintitle = {Willkommen im Club},
    number = {80},
    subtitle = {},
    title = {Ich fühle mich nicht als Teil der queeren Community!},
    url = {https://www.ardaudiothek.de/episode/willkommen-im-club-der-queere-podcast-von-puls/ich-fuehle-mich-nicht-als-teil-der-queeren-community-80/puls/12041705/},
    urldate = {2023-03-16},
    year = {2022},
}
@audio{vanduck,
    author = {given=Paulinho, family=Duck, prefix={van (Author)} and given=Paulette, family=Quack, prefix={de la (Host)}},
    date = {2020-05-03},
    entrysubtype = {Youtube video},
    mainsubtitle = {This is a subtitle},
    maintitle = {This is a main title},
    number = {10},
    subtitle = {},
    title = {Ducks are smart},
    url = {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVtcV6mw430},
    urldate = {2023-04-25},
}
@article{vanduckart,
    author = {given=Paulinho, family=Duck, prefix={van}},
    date = {2020-05-03},
    title = {Ducks are smart},
    journal={Journal of Sempione Park University},
    year={2016},
    number={1},
    volume={3}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{audio.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{audio}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  role,
  }
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[audio]{
  author,
  role,
  date,
  entrysubtype,
  mainsubtitle,
  maintitle,
  number,
  subtitle,
  title,
  url,
  urldate,
  year
  }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[
    paper=A4,
    pagesize=auto
    12pt,
    ngerman,
    usegeometry,
    oneside,
    headinclude=false,
    footinclude=true,
    BCOR=0mm,
    DIV=calc,
    parskip=onehalf,
    bibliography=totocnumbered,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[
    datamodel=audio,
    toc=bibliographynumbered, 
    style=authoryear-ibid,
    ]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{/}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}

\DeclareFieldFormat[audio]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{role}{\MakeUppercase #1}
\newbibmacro*{role}{%
    \iffieldundef{role}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\printfield{role}}}%
  }

\DeclareFieldFormat[audio]{entrysubtype}{\MakeUppercase #1}
\newbibmacro*{entrysubtype}{%
    \iffieldundef{entrysubtype}
    {}
    {\printfield{entrysubtype}}%
  }

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
    urlfrom = {Verfügbar unter\addcolon},%
    urlseen = {zuletzt geprüft\addcolon},
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[audio]{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[audio]{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}

\newbibmacro*{audiourl}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}
    {}
    {\bibstring{urlfrom}\addspace\printfield{url}%
        \iffieldundef{urlyear}
        {}
        {\addspace\usebibmacro{urldate}}%
    }
  }
  
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{audio}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{role}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle}%
  \usebibmacro{entrysubtype}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{audiourl}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
  
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

\begin{document}
Wie in Kapitel 2 hinlänglich beschrieben handelt es sich bei Queerness \MakeUppercase nicht um eine 
Szeneangehörigkeit, sondern primär um das Abweichen der sexuellen Orientierung und/oder 
Geschlechtsidentität eines Menschen von der gesellschaftlichen Norm. In manchen Kontexten 
lässt sich zwar durchaus von einer queeren Szene sprechen, diese ist jedoch höchst heterogen,
oftmals lokal fragmentiert, und es gehören nicht alle queeren Menschen auch zwangsläufig 
dieser Szene an \parencite[vgl.][]{WiC80}. 

This is another citation \parencite[vgl.][]{vanduck}.

This is a citation of an article \parencite[vgl.][]{vanduckart}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Citation:

[image]

Bibliography:

[image]

Comment: +1 (not only but also) for the Youtube link.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Hahahahahahahahaha Thank you for upvoting